# Using content called from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a simple link.  The issue is the file name is going to come from the database.

example: `<a href="foldername/**FileNameInSQL.zip**">Download</a>`

I have not worked much with MYSQL and have pieced together something that is working so far

```
<?php
$products_id = $_GET['id'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 

$sql = "select * from znc_product_extra_fields where products_id = '" . $products_id . "'"; 

$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
echo $row['file_1']; 
}

?>
```

When I run it it does just what I want, it echos the file name that is assigned to that specific row (item number)

But I am lost how to turn this into the link. The only thing I can think is somehow assigning this result to a variable and calling it while creating the link but I do not know how to take this result which is correct and actually use it! How would I take this filename and place in the link

`<a href="foldername/**FileNameInSQL.zip**">Download</a>`

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @tereško It's saddening how many times that comment has to be copied and pasted `:P`.

Comment: @JamWaffles , well , i originally made it `=P`

Comment: @tereško Ah, but you've pasted it into that comment box though `;)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP outputs whatever you want it to - text, HTML, XML, etc.  So just output the HTML. I think what you want is:

`echo "<a href=\"foldername/".$row['file_1']."\">Download</a>";`

Although you shouldn't be using the outdated mysql_* functions.  Please see [PDO](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) (the best option) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

To prevent SQL injection, use [PDO::quote](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) (if you are using PDO), or [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (if you are using mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<a href="/folder/' . $row['file_1'] . '">file</a>;`

- Your code is vulnerable to MySQL injection. Use `real_escape_string`
  on your `GET, POST` parameters.
- You should use PDO (see tereško comment for reason)